# Fix transfer of ASCII encoded binary file over serial transfer

Tags: linux, vim, encoding, serial-port, ascii

I'm trying to move a binary file from a host Linux system to a remote system. Since the remote system does not have internet capabilities, I'm sending the file serially. I first encode the file to ascii using uuencode. There's no issues until the file is transferred. During transfer, empty lines are added between every line of text, so the uudecode will not work. I can edit the received file manually in vim to remove the line breaks, but this is only feasible for "Hello world" size files. I've looked up how to use macros in vim to expedite the process, but it seems the package I have on the remote system is missing the features I need. I can't record macros with q, or execute global commands with g (vi returns 'not implemented' when pressing either key). Since I don't have internet to update the remote system, I figure I have to correct the issue at the transfer stage. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can do this?

If it's relevant, I'm using minicom as my serial terminal to send ascii files. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3):

So this is more of a workaround than a solution, but switching the file transfer protocol in minicom from using ASCII to Zmodem and the lrzsz package eliminates the error of adding line breaks during file transfer. The file on the remote system can be decoded immediately with no edits.

Comment: not a workaround, this is the solution. You had the wrong settings for your serial communications setup, (so you could fix that, but that would take a lot of back and forth). So you're lucky to discover the Zmodem is another valid solution that does the serial setup for you ;-) . Good luck.